# CSS Challenge: INPUT going outside of DIV

Tags: css, html, css-float

I'm trying to accomplish something specific around platform constraints I'm under.

I created a somewhat self-explanatory jsfiddle of the problem at http://jsfiddle.net/MrV5M/4/

The specific problem:

- On Chrome, the right border of the input box is cut off.
- On Safari, the width of the content class cell exceeds the container so it spills over the border.
- On IE9, the label doesn't float to the left of the content div

The main reason I care about Safari is because I'm working on a JQuery Mobile/PhoneGap app which is also a web app.  I'm only supporting modern browsers, but this is driving me nuts.  Normally I'd just use a table for the container, but the text-overflow: ellipsis styles on the content div don't work when inside a table.  (Basically, I'm trying to keep the content to a single line and have ellipsis without enforcing a fixed width or calculating a width with Javascript)

Anyone have the l33t CSS skills to make this work?  I sure don't...  :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you are trying to do, but if you insist on using 'flex' stuff which is largely un-supported (even in the majors [see here](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)), you'll need to add the vendor prefixes to `flex`.

e.g... `-webkit-flex`, `-moz-flex`

Also, I don't think you need to be setting widths on elements that have the flex property.. not positive though.

So your browser issues:

-IE doesn't support flex at all so you're label won't float unless you use a float.

-The reason your input/content is spilling over the container and getting cut off is not really anything to do with flex.. but the way css works.. setting an element to 100% width means setting it to the width of its parent.  But by default, css doesn't count the padding/border-width as part of that width. So you end up getting 100% width plus the L/R padding and border.  But, since you are only supporting modern browsers.. `box-sizing:border-box;` to the rescue.  Google it for details, but putting it on your input element should do the trick.

Comment: Great suggestions brains!  I'll play with it a bit and post an update.

Comment: Hi Brains - thanks for the tips, especially box-sizing.  I think I got it to work as best as possible.   See http://jsfiddle.net/MrV5M/22/ - works on IE9, Safari, Chrome and Firefox.  (With a little browser detection required)  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Just add this CSS to your Stylesheet, and get peace of mind on your issue :D

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not like this answer. I made some adjustments in the css which fixes Chrome and IE9 issues. Take a look,

http://jsfiddle.net/MrV5M/11/

Comment: That's definitely closer, though it doesn't work in Sarfari.  I really appreciate the try, though.  I'll try playing with of these ideas and see if anything works..